# Maximum and minimum for random variable

Tags: random-variables, standard-deviation

Assuming that the standard deviation is given as 1 and the mean is 0, can I assume that any random variable generated with the normal distribution won't be less than -4 and greater than +4 based on the 68–95–99.7 rule? Should I clamp the set if I want to impose this constraint?

Comment: No, but a value greater than $4$ or smaller than $-4$ is even more unlikely. The random variable can have any value, but the probability drastically decreases with growing absolute value.

Comment: If the question refers to the practical meaning : Values outside the interval $[-4,4]$ are so unlikely, that we can assume that the given random variable is not standard-normal-distributed, if such a value occurs in a single experiment. This is the basis of hypothesis-tests.